# MacBook Air Intel keyboard issues on Ubuntu MATE

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, shortcut-keys, macbook, ubuntu-mate

I installed the current Ubuntu MATE 22.04 on my old MacBook Air Intel and everything looks great, except for the so-called "Common editing shortcuts" (CTRL+C, CTRL+X ...).

I tried various combinations with the CTRL and Command keys, but nothing helped.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Then, open keyboard settings (within settings app), and open the "Layouts" tab.

Click on Keyboard model and choose `Apple | Macbook/Macbook Pro`.

Comment: I did, but not working.